# Coldfusion and Regular expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to use regular expressions in ColdFusion 10 to find some data in an html
source page. I used the following regex on my texteditor which results in the desired 
output. When I go and try to use coldfusion it throws an error

`<Cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"name=('|"")(\w*)\1\s*value=('|"")(\w*)\3.*$","\n#$2\t$4","ALL")>
<Cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"^[^#].*$\R","","ALL")>
<Cfset foo = ReReplaceNoCase(foo,"\R\R","\n","ALL")>`

Comment: Regular Expression flags and special characters are case sensitive. You may find your result replacing the matched string with RR (if that is your intent, the preceding slashes aren't needed). You need to use lowercase flags in this case. `\r\r`. For instance, `\w` matches any alphanumeric character and underscore, whereas `\W` matches any character that is not.

Comment: *Re: throws an error* What is the actual error message? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26938706/edit) your question to include the error thrown.

Comment: Backreferences in CF look like this: `\1`, `\2` rather than this: `$1`,`$2`. But I suspect the error is due to the fact that the pound signs `#` are not escaped. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e91.html

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape pound signs in strings in ColdFusion.  Try using `##` wherever you use `#`.